# SVM Model with a Poly Kernel

Tags: python, svm, spyder

Hi everyone dumby me here again stuck on another thing. So I am trying to create a function with a SVM using a ploy kernel. I thought I had it but then I plugged in some numbers to check my work and now I'm getting an error.

> TypeError: poly_grid_search() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given.

Here is my code...

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


brc = np.loadtxt('brc-1.txt', delimiter=',')
X = brc[:,1:-1]
Y = brc[:,-1]
trainX, testX, trainY,testY = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size = 0.4, random_state = 12345678)
trainX.shape,testX.shape,trainY.shape,testY.shape
lsvm.fit(trainX,trainY)
lsvm.predict(testX)
lsvm.predict(trainX)
lsvm.score(testX,testY)
psvm=svm.SVC(kernel='poly',degree=2)
psvm.fit(trainX,trainY)
#%%
C=[]
D=[]
X=[0.01,0.1,1,10]
def poly_grid_search():
    lsvm = svm.SVC(kernel='poly', C=10)
    rsvm=svm.SVC(Kernel='rbf',gamma=D)
    rsvm.fit(trainX,trainY)
    print("polynomial kernel degree = {}, cost = {}, testing acurracy rate {}".format(X,rsvm.score(trainX,trainY)))
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error seems like you are passing two arguments when calling `poly_grid_search`. Since the signature of the function `poly_grid_search` doesn't have any argument an error like the one you are getting could be possible. Basically, instead of just doing `poly_grid_search()` to get such error you maybe are doing something like `poly_grid_search(arg1, arg2)` where `arg1` and `arg2` are some variables or values in the full piece of code that you are running

Comment: Thank you so much that really helps!

Comment: No problem, glad that it was useful!